# How to Add Multiprocessing or Threads for a loop of operations? Python

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading

I need a little tutorial: How to add multithreaded operations in a loop ?. I have a loop that call other functions, update a progress bar in the GUI Tkinter and other operations and such operations need to run faster, as my GUI locks. Any idea how to do ?, for example, how you would add if it (Of course, considering that have transactions with the GUI, such as updating the progress bar in the loop.)

```
def MakeSum(a, b):
    s = a + b

    return s

def GoDiv(a, b):

    div = a / b

    return div

def Process():

    for i in range(10):

        result = MakeSum(i, i)

        print("Result of the sum of " + str(i) + " + " + str(i) +
                  " = " + str(result))

        try:
            final = GoDiv(result, i)

        except:
            print("Denominator Is Zero, can't Div")

        else:
            print("Result of the Div of " + str(result) + " / " + str(i) +
                      " = " + str(final))
Process()
```

Basically what my loop is walking a directory and search images. After the search and opens with PIL image, I extract the text PyTesseract.I call a function that searches me exactly what I want from the extracted image text. Once done, I cut the image and renamed with the text fragment extracted. Update the progress bar at each iteration and handling exceptions such as in the code above.

Is it possible to optimize all that ?. I analyzed the complexity of the algorithms implemented in the functions that I'm calling and are only O (L) where L is the length of string, to find what I want.

PS: I can not paste all the code here as it is slightly polluted and is very long. I am in process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There should be lots of information on this in the internet. Have you tried googling?

Comment: I tried googling to find a tutorial, the problem is that there are a lot of threads and explain what is a little out of what I want. Threads as they apply to transactions that are outside of a loop. I wish I could give an example if I showed up. Thank you very much for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you need to realize is that in tkinter, only the main thread is allowed to update the screen, so any other threads couldn't update the progress bar.  If you have a long-running loop, tkinter will not update the screen until the loop is done, leaving the impression that the GUI is locked.  The way to deal with this is to call the `update_idletasks` method of one of your widgets.

The idea is that Tk only updates the screen when it has nothing else to do (when it is idle.)  The call to `update_idletasks` forces it to perform now the tasks that it would otherwise defer until it became idle.

Without seeing the code, I can't give a specific suggestion about when to call `update_idletasks`, of course.

I hope this helps.

EDIT: Read this post: [update idletasks when toplevel hasn't the focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282468/update-idletasks-when-toplevel-hasnt-the-focus)  Anything Donal Fellows has to say about Tk/tkinter is much more worth reading than anything I have to say.